# How to check Symbolic Link to a directory?

Tags: c++, unix, symlink

```
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 t domain users 4096 Nov 3 17:55 original
lrwxrwxrwx 1 t domain users    8 Nov 3 17:56 symbolic -> original
```

Here symbolic is a symbolic link pointing to original folder.

Contents of original folder.

```
$ ls -l original/
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 2 t domain users 4096  Nov  3 17:55 mydoc.docx
```

I have a file path in my code like:

```
std::string fileName = "/home/Downloads/symbolic/mydoc.docx";
path filePath(fileName);
```

How to check if fileName is a symbolic link?

is_symlink(filePath) is returning false and read_symlink(filePath) is returning empty path.
I want to use canonical only if it is symbolic link. Like this:

```
if(is_symlink(filePath)) --> This is returning false.Any other alternative ?
{
  newFilePath = canonical(filePath);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean not working? have you tried https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_symlink ?

Comment: is_symlink will return false and read_symlink will return empty path.

Comment: That seems to be correct behaviour. only `/home/Downloads/symbolic` is a symlink, `/home/Downloads/symbolic/mydoc.docx` is not a symlink. did you want to use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical perhaps?

Comment: But i want to go for canonical only if symbolic links exists in a path. That's why I was using is_symlink as a check. I want a replacement for is_symlink since it is returning false for directories symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page, is_symlink need a filesystem::path as parameter, not a std::string. You may want to try that.

Comment: path can be implicitly constructed from std::string

Comment: Well, he did not elaborate what "are not working correctly" means, so we have to guess.

Comment: Sorry for not giving full info .Just edited.